# CodeIgniter Transactions Commit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a schedule, and I want the user to just add specific data on his schedule, but it will not `COMMIT`upon "inserting" it on his schedule. The schedule will be saved when he clicked the button SAVE CHANGES.

Here is my code:

```
function addSubjectToSchedule(){
$this->dbsections->trans_begin();
$data = array(
                'SUBJ_ID' => $subj_id,
                'SUBJ_CODE' => $subj_code,
                'SUBJ_NAME' => $subj_name,
                'SECTION_ID' => $section_id,
                'SECTION_NAME' => $section_name,
                'TEACHER_ID' => $teacher,
                'DAYS' => $strday,
                'TIME_START' => $hstart.':'.$mstart.':00',
                'TIME_END' => $hend.':'.$mend.':00',
                'SECTION_ROOM' => $section_room
        );

        $this->dbsections->insert('schedules', $data);
}
```

Here is the method that will be called upon clicking the **Revert Changes** button

```
public function rollback(){
        $this->dbsections->trans_rollback();
    }
```

And here is the method that will be called upon clicking the **Save** button.

```
function commit(){
        $this->dbsections->trans_commit();
    }
```

But when I click it, the data is not saved in the database.

Comment: Replace 'TIME_END' => $hend.':'.$mend.':00', with 'TIME_END' => ".$hend.':'.$mend.':00'",

Comment: Nope, it didn't helped

Comment: same for TIME_START and for all string

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't changed anything

Comment: alternatively you can echo your query from model and see what the output is .

Comment: I am trying to echo `trans_status()` and it shows `1`

Comment: It will never save at your database.because `$this->dbsections` is not same object for two different server call.Why don't you just save it when save button is called.